# Php echo wont apply in text correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I created my first WordPress plugin, its simple, here is the code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: blabla
*/
function wp_first_shortcode(){
    echo "Hello, This is your another shortcode!";
}
add_shortcode('first', 'wp_first_shortcode');
?>
```

In wp post, I have an article, like this:

```
text text text [first] text text
```

But the result I see is:

```
[first]
text text text text text
```

`[first]` - is the shortcode, that must show text from my plugin -  echo "Hello, This is your another shortcode!";

Here is the link to live example www cpamethods.com/instagram-management/

Comment: Problem solved!, read @Elentriel answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On shortcodes on WordPress, return, don't echo

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: blabla
*/
function wp_first_shortcode(){
    return "Hello, This is your another shortcode!";
}
add_shortcode('first', 'wp_first_shortcode');
?>
```

Also be sure to activate your plugin before using the shortcode

Comment: WOW MATE, YOU'RE GURU, I WILL TRY THIS RIGHT NOW.

Comment: Oh my, this code is working, MAN SO MUCH THATNKS, just tired to search  on google, cant even find it and you solve it in minutes, omg, cant believe your answer was so fast. GURU. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure, mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.
Also i would recomend reading straight from https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
WordPress has an excelent manual.